# Unable to pass SelectionMode as DependencyProperty for ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a listview inside user control, and the user control is called on a page. I want to decide what will be the `SelectionMode` of the `ListView` from my page. To achieve this I have created a dependency property inside user control like this

```
public ListViewSelectionMode SelectionMode
{
    get { return (ListViewSelectionMode)GetValue(SelectionModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectionModeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectionModeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectionMode", typeof(ListViewSelectionMode), typeof(EditMultiSelectComboBoxControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

XAML

```
<ListView SelectionMode="{x:Bind lvSelectionMode}"></ListView>
```

And on my main page, I am initializing this user control like this:

```
<local:myuc Loaded="UC_Loaded"  ></local:myuc>
```

Code behind

```
private void UC_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MultiCombo.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;
}
```

All looks good to me, but when I run the project no item inside Listview is clickable / selectable. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended that you use `OneWay` binding mode, so that after loading, changes to control dependent properties will still be reflected on the UI

```xml
<ListView SelectionMode="{x:Bind lvSelectionMode, Mode=OneWay}"></ListView>
```

Thanks.